# Future variables and null safety: Non-nullable instance field 'notifications' must be initialized

Tags: dart, future

I've recently upgraded Dart (using v2.12.4) and [trying to migrate](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) an app I've made.

I'm now stuck at an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```dart
class Notifications {
    Future<List<NotificationItem>> notificationItems;

    fillNotificationList() async {
        notificationItems = await httpService.getFromEndpoint();
    }
}
```

The `notificationItems` currently errors with `Non-nullable instance field 'notifications' must be initialized.`.

I've tried different solutions; adding `late` keyword makes the application throw a `LateInitializationError` exception and appending  `= []` gives a type error.

How can I successfully have a Future variable with the null safety features in recent versions of Dart?

Comment: Why aren't you just returning the Future directly from the class, and let the caller store it in a non-nullable variable?  No need for await or async then either, although you'll need to declare the function to return a Future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a nullable variable. Meaning there is a point in time in your program where this is clearly `null`. So declare it as such:

```
Future<List<NotificationItem>>? notificationItems;
```

The rest of your code seems a little weird to me. You named a future like I would name the actual result. You have an async method that doesn't do any async work. Maybe that's just because the example here is simplified.

Or maybe you really really want to insist this is never null. You could initialize it with a completed Future with an empty list:

```
Future<List<NotificationItem>>? notificationItems = Future.value(<NotificationItem>[]);
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. The code sample is simplified, but it does represent some logic that I'm actually using. The `fillNotificationList()` fetches paginated results (for lazy loading) and is set to fill the `notificationItems` list. I can clearly see that I forgot an `await` in my async function (edited).